# Opening numeric keypad for text field

Tags: ionic-framework, input-field, numeric-keypad

I am using Ionic framework 2.2.1. I have a text input field for which, in almost 99% case, the input value will be a number. So I would like to open a numeric keypad when a user focuses on this field. Is there any way to do this?

I have tried `<input type="text" pattern="\d*">` and it's not working. I also can't use `<input type="tel">` or `<input type="number">` since the value can have alphabetic characters too.

Answer (score 0):

If you do this the user wouldn't be able to input alphanumeric values anymore, as the keypad only allows numbers.